# Rhino and DOM support

Tags: javascript, dom, rhino

Does Rhino have support for using DOM objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM is not part of core ECMAScript; it is usually provided by the browser the ECMAScript engine runs on.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, [E4X](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-ajax1/#N100B1) is a simple DOM implementation...perhaps better than the normal Java DOM implementation.

Comment: +1 for pointing towards E4X. Looks like an excellent alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link to E4X!